# The process cannot access the file because error while trying to write to a file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting this error when i am trying to write to a file in this manner:

```
    try
    {

        if (!File.Exists(path))
            File.CreateText(file.ToString());

        sw = flag == 1 ? File.CreateText(file.ToString()) : File.AppendText(file.ToString()); //Exception here

        sw.WriteLine(textToWrite);

        status = true;
    }
```

But before to this file i made a delete attempt to it also in another function in this way:

```
    try
    {
        File.Delete(path);
        status = true;
    }
```

Exception:
`{"The process cannot access the file ... because it is being used by another process."}`

Now as it seems file is still either taken by delete process of by the `File.CreateText` function, how can i make them release the file so i can start writing to it?

Answer (score 1):

[File.CreateText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return a streamwriter which has a file stream still **opened**. You should be using that. That is the reason why you get exception in successive calls to open the file.

Try this.

```
using(var sw = File.CreateText(...))
{
    //Do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the file before writing a new file, try this:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, textToWrite);
```

If you want to append to a file (or create), try this:

```
File.AppendAllText(path, textToWrite);
```

Both of these methods close the file after writing.

Answer (score 0):

CreateText returns StremWriter which you miss it. That's why it remains opened. You can easily close it:

```
StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path);
sr.WriteLine(textToWrite);
sr.Close();
```